# Uncover points of scatterplot

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, overlays

have a a plot that is similar to this (almost) minimal example here:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line = bottom,
            axis y line = left,
            ]

            \addplot3[
                samples at = {1.3, 2, 2.55, 3.5, 5.7, 12},
                samples y =0,
                point meta=(x-0.5)^2 + y^2,
                mark = *,
                only marks,
                scatter,
                ]
                ({sin(x)}, {cos(x)}, {1/x});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to uncover the single samples one at a time with beamer overlays?

Answer (score 4):

A version not using any library, just adding `\pause` via `scatter/@post marker code`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line = bottom,
            axis y line = left,
            scatter/@pre marker code/.code={},
            scatter/@post marker code/.code={\pause}
            ]

            \addplot3[
                samples at = {1.3, 2, 2.55, 3.5, 5.7, 12},
                samples y =0,
                point meta=(x-0.5)^2 + y^2,
                mark =*,
                only marks,
                scatter,
                ]
                ({sin(x)}, {cos(x)}, {1/x});
        \end{axis}
     \onslide<1->% see comments
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are a mighty magician, you can make footlines disappear :)  Try e.g. with `\usetheme{Boadilla}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I was just happy to get the `\pause` injected. (Is this salvageable, or should I delete?)

Comment: I know the feeling :) You can add a `\onslide<1->` before the end of the tikzpicture.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I like this answer but it seems harder to use in more complex scenarios, e.g., I want to uncover the points from overlay 5-10.

Comment: @Franz I used up my beamer knowledge , we could try pinging samcarter again though:-)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ^^ :-)

Comment: @Franz `\pause` is a very crude command. if it happens to do what you need, that's great because it is easy to use. If you need more fine control, I'd go for explicit overlays.

Comment: Ok. I don't see how I could do that with `scatter/@post marker code/.code` if I want the points to be shown at specific overlays; let's say 5, 7, 10, 11, 12, 20.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line = bottom,
            axis y line = left,
            ]

            \addplot3[
                samples at = {1.3, 2, 2.55, 3.5, 5.7,12},
                samples y =0,
                point meta=(x-0.5)^2 + y^2,
                mark = *,
                only marks,
                scatter,
                scatter src=z,
                scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped
                color!80!black,fill=mapped color,visible on=<+->}
            ]
                ({sin(x)}, {cos(x)}, {1/x});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. You gave the hint with `overlay-beamer-styles` just two days ago in another post of mine. I didn't see how I could use it here. Ty.

Comment: @Franz You're welcome!

Comment: Where can I actually find the documentation for tikz libraries? I tried to search for "CTAN overlay-beamer-styles" but did not find anything useful. The tikz/pgfplots documentation also does not mention it.

Comment: @Franz https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz

Comment: Ok. The name was so obscure that I didn't recognized it as `overlay-beamer-styles`. The documentation and the features also seem kind of sparse, e.g., I was looking for an `alert on=` command but could find it.

Comment: @Franz Remembering the name is the biggest challenge in using this package :) I always have trouble to get the order of the letters right :)

Comment: @Franz ... aobs only implements a subset of beamer overlay names for the use as tikz styles. As the beamer alert is basically just a colour change, you can probably replace it by changing the draw or fill colour on the overlays you want something to be alerted

Comment: (I'm half tempted to write a package with the name `the-package-I-can't-remember` which would do nothing but `\RequirePackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` )