Animated plot that takes points in a .txt as an input
A have a large .txt file where each line contains the coordinates of some points in the plane. For example, the first 4 lines are as follows:
(4.486912934894983e-16,1.0)
(1.0,-3.3306690738754696e-16) (0.9999999999999998,-4.996003610813204e-16)
(-0.5257311121191334,0.85065080835204) (0.9999999999999998,-3.9720546451956367e-16) (0.5257311121191337,0.8506508083520395)
(-0.9222837188593067,0.38651357275915543) (0.8959532196631044,-0.4441484303420613) (1.1434777446585544e-15,1.0) (0.895953219663105,0.4441484303420605)

I would like to create an animated TikZ plot in a Beamer presentation that sequentially displays the points from the file. The animation would begin by showing the point from the first line, then the points from the second line, and so on, with each new set of points appearing every second. (The new points do not get added to the plot, they replace the previous ones.)
Although I know how to plot points using TikZ, manually inputting the data is impractical given the file size (around 100 lines). Therefore, I’m looking for a way to automate the process. Specifically, I need the .tex file to automatically open the .txt file and loop through each line to plot the points.
Is it possible to do this in LaTeX? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: Here's a non-automated version of what I want. There are two problems with it. Firstly, it requires manually adding all the points, which becomes infeasible very quick. Also, for some reason, the circles in the animation bulge inward and outward. (I don't know how to upload the .pdf generated by this code in here, unfortunately.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{5} % 5fps animation
    %%% Frame 1 - Plot points from the first line of the .txt file
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
            
        % Add points for frame 1 (read from the first line of the .txt file)
        \fill (4.486912934894983e-16,1.0) circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newframe

    %%% Add additional frames similarly by reading new lines from the file
    %%% For Frame 2:
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle [radius=1];

        % Add points for frame 2 (from the second line of the .txt file)
        \fill (1.0,-3.3306690738754696e-16) circle (2pt);
        \fill (0.9999999999999998,-4.996003610813204e-16) circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newframe
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle [radius=1];

        % Add points for frame 3 (from the third line of the .txt file)
        \fill (-0.5257311121191334,0.85065080835204) circle (2pt);
        \fill (0.9999999999999998,-3.9720546451956367e-16) circle (2pt);
        \fill (0.5257311121191337,0.8506508083520395) circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newframe
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle [radius=1];

        % Add points for frame 4 (from the fourth line of the .txt file)
        \fill (-0.9222837188593067,0.38651357275915543) circle (2pt);
        \fill (0.8959532196631044,-0.4441484303420613) circle (2pt);
        \fill (1.1434777446585544e-15,1.0) circle (2pt);
        \fill (0.895953219663105,0.4441484303420605) circle (2pt);
        \fill (0.9222837188593082,0.3865135727591564) circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    %%% Continue adding frames for all lines in the file...
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}


Yes, it is possible. Can you paste the first, say, 20 lines from your txt file? How should the points look like? The two points of your second line are very close together: (2, 0)

Dear @Qrrbrbirlbel, the points will be better and better approximations of the unit circle. (They were not normalized to be of radius one in the image above, but I now normalized it.) You can find the .txt file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x2IBREsrzxADbUrxA8vb8XyA8pEQKgAf/view?usp=sharing

Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653242/36296 could be a starting point. Please add a small, but compilable test file to your question.

Dear @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz as I've said, I know how to do this "by hand", but I don't know how to automate it. (And this is absolutely necessary since the amount of points grows very fast.) I've added a MWE.

Can you replace the image of your data file with actual text?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done!

The data file coords2.txt is read line by line within animate's \multiframe loop from which the programme flow breaks out with \multiframebreak on end-of-file or after reading an empty line.
Pkg listofitems is used to split the lines at the spaces between the coordinates and to store the coordinates of the current frame in the list variable \coords. Over the latter we iterate with \foreachitem to put each dot at its individual coordinate.
\useasboundingbox ... sets the same, fixed-size bounding box for each frame.
PDF output
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \fileopenr{<file stream>}{<file name>}, opens file for reading
\newcommand\fileopenr[2]{%
  \newread#1%
  \immediate\openin#1=#2%
}
% \readtolist[<sep char>]{<file stream>}{\list}
% reads a line from file stream and splits at <sep char> into \list[1], \list[2], ...
\newcommand\readtolist[3][,]{{%
  \setsepchar{#1}\endlinechar=-1%
  \immediate\read#2 to \inputline%
  \ifeof#2
    \immediate\closein#2%
    \ifdefined\multiframebreak\multiframebreak\fi%
  \else%
    \ifx\inputline\empty%
      \immediate\closein#2%
      \ifdefined\multiframebreak\multiframebreak\fi%
    \else\greadlist*#3\inputline\fi%
  \fi%
}}
\usepackage{listofitems} % read space separated items
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Points and a circle}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{5}
  \fileopenr{\data}{coords2.txt}%
  \readtolist[ ]{\data}{\coords}
  \multiframe{10000}{}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox circle[radius=1.1];
      \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
      \foreachitem\coord\in\coords{
        \fill \coord circle (2pt);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \readtolist[ ]{\data}{\coords}
  }  
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


This is perfect @AlexG, thank you.

This uses l3file to read the file. The macro \QrrFileReadLines saves a line into \QRRLINE and executes its argument for each line where \QRRLINE is used as coordinates for a plot that places filled circle as marks.
It seems that the \ior_if_eof test doesn't triger when the last line – I've removed any empty lines at the end of the file – has been read.
This means that the last frame is blank.
It might be necessary to read the lines manually instead of using the practcal \ior_str_map_variable function.
Code
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\QrrFileOpen}{m}{ \ior_new:N \g__qrr_file \ior_open:Nn \g__qrr_file { #1 } }
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\QrrFileReadLines}{m}{ \ior_str_map_variable:NNn \g__qrr_file \QRRLINE { #1 } }
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\QrrFileClose}{}{ \ior_close:N \g__qrr_file }
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\QrrFileIfEof}{mm}{ \ior_if_eof:NTF \g__qrr_file { #1 }{ #2 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\QrrFileOpen{coords2.txt}
\begin{frame}{Points and a circle}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{5}
\QrrFileReadLines{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \useasboundingbox ([shift={(-\pgfplotmarksize,-\pgfplotmarksize)}]-1,-1)
                      ([shift={( \pgfplotmarksize, \pgfplotmarksize)}] 1, 1);
    \draw plot[only marks, mark=*] coordinates {\QRRLINE};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \QrrFileIfEof{}{\newframe}%
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\QrrFileClose
\end{document}


Dear @Qrrbrbirlbel, this is very good! Thank you! Do you know if there's a way of creating another tikzpicture with the last frame just before the \end{animateinline}? Perhaps this would solve the problem of the last frame being blank.

@Gabriel The manual way seems to be the better approach, see AlexG's answer.
